# Interrupt fails to change variable, how so?

Tags: microcontroller, avr, atmega, c, interrupts

Problem was virtually undebuggable, the interrupt that was changing a variable would *randomly* fail to do so, with no apparent pattern; within interrupt code variable would change but outside of it the change is essentially reverted back to previous state. It's a regular variable so it's not double-buffered. Marking it as volatile had no effect (besides making the code run slower). I've already worked around the problem, but phenomena is still there nonetheless. Also, my chip is Atmega644 and language is C.

I have narrower down the problem to a following code: the interrupt was firing during the execution of code that was also writing to that variable. It checked for pin state, and depending on it would either set or clear a bit from that variable. I resolved the issue by putting that code in the interrupt as well, which left interruptable code with not a single place where that variable was written - only read.

The code is substantially long, so I only provide relevant snippets (the rest of the code doesn't even deals with related variables):

```
#define BIT(x) (1<<(x))
#define BITSET(x,y) ((x)|=(y))
#define BITCLR(x,y) ((x)&=~(y))

//Interrupt snippet:
if ( PINB & BIT(PINB0) )
    BITSET( display, BIT(DSPL_PWR) );
if ( PINB & BIT(PINB1) )
    BITSET( display, BIT(DSPL_ACT) );

//Main code:
if ( PIND & BIT(PIND2) )
    BITSET( display, BIT(DSPL_ACC) );
else
    BITCLR( display, BIT(DSPL_ACC) );

<...>
leds_display = 0x00;
switch ( roll )
{
    case 0:
        leds_display |= display & BIT(DSPL_PWR);
        break;
    //etc.
}
PORTA = leds_display;
```

However, that is but a crutch-fix. It works that way, but it should've worked the way it was. Changing a variable is atomic operation, so it can not be interrupted mid-action. My guess was that it was due to optimization magic, but then volatile would have changed the behavior. And even then, even without volatile marker, the code may have ignored the change the first time it ran (it's not critical for it to be real-time up to date), but the next iteration would have recognized the change. This leaves me puzzled about nature of the phenomena.

Anyone knows anything about it? Or is it just a compiler bug?

Comment: Code, please...

Comment: Changing a variable is most certainly not atomic.

Comment: Without code the whole bunch of words up there is useless. It can be anything.

Comment: I honestly can't imagine why anyone would need an actual code to see into the problem, but there you go.

Comment: While 'volatile' is usually necessary when accessing the same variable from both interrupt & main code if you have any optimisation going on, it is most definitely NOT a magical fix-all which makes all variable operations atomic.

Comment: @RaidhoCoaxil Because the problem might be totally different from what you are thinking of.

Comment: And the micro you're using? Compiler and version?

Comment: So which variable is not updating? Is it `display` ? How is it declared?

Comment: @brhans I've mentioned controller model in OP, it's Atmega644; compiler is ARMGCC 3.3.1.

Comment: Before making various bold statements about compiler bugs, have you **disassembled the code**? Looking at the code posted, I'd dismiss this as a standard read-modify-write issue. If it was an optimization bug caused by lack of volatile, the bug would have been consistent and not seemingly random.

Answer (score 5):

It is highly unlikely that you have discovered a compiler problem.

Plain and simple.....many variable modifications will require the CPU to perform a read-modify-write behavior to the memory location. If your interrupt comes in the middle of that process you will have undefined behavior.

The fix for it in the mainline code is to bracket the variable modification with a sequence like...

```
disable interrupts

modify variable

re-enable interrupts
```

Note that most embedded C compilers have specialized macros that you can invoke to perform the disable/re-enable steps. It is often typical that these only take one machine instruction each and so the overhead is very low.

There is sometimes a need to perform a somewhat more robust code protection scheme in cases where the mainline program code may run with or without interrupts enabled from time to time. This case can also come up if a subroutine or library function is called from both the mainline context and the interrupt context - and the called function needs variable code protection. In these cases it is common to have to implement as:

```
save current interrupt enabled state (most often to stack)

disable interrupts

modify variable

restore current interrupt enable state (most often from stack)
```

Comment: I think you mean "it is highly unlikely that you have discovered a compiler problem"

Comment: I have tried disabling interrupts temporarily but that ended up with timed interrupt failing to fire. That is I knew that would happen but I gave it a go anyway and it indeed happened. Instead of failing to change a variable, the interrupt wasn't firing altogether. Not an option.

Comment: @NickJohnson - Thanks for pointing out my stray "not". It has been removed.

Comment: @RaidhoCoaxil - You have more figuring out then. You will highly likely have to follow the points I made in this posting. Every embedded application I've made in 30 years that used variables in interrupts usually required this strategy!! If your timer interrupt failed to fire it is due to some other cause. You will have to figure out why.

Comment: @MichaelKaras Well my idea of it is that if it fails to change variable if it fires exactly the moment the variable is being accessed elsewhere, then disabling an interrupts for that time frame would result in interrupt simply not firing if timer happened to overflow in that exact moment. Am I wrong and it should have fired upon setting interrupts flag, and I should look for answers elsewhere in my code? Also, I've checked the assembly and it was working with registers, not memory.

Comment: @RaidhoCoaxil - if you are talking about the timer interrupt, then it is queued and will fire as soon as you re-activate interrupts. Which timer is it?

Comment: @RaidhoCoaxil - If you disable interrupts around your mainline variable modification and a timer interrupt comes along while in the disabled window then its interrupt should happen right after you re-enable. If that is not then case then you are doing something to accidentally clear the queued timer interrupt flag whilst things are disabled.

Comment: @Jon Ok thanks, I've done plenty of tinkering with that one, so I guess I just have left somewhere a piece that was clearing interrupt flags.

Comment: @RaidhoCoaxil - The interrupt enable / disable flag you probably want to be working with here is the main CPU global interrupt enable flag. There are of course some special cases where you may have designed your code to use interrupt priorities and are re-enabling interrupts inside your ISRs for higher priority cases to be able to superseded some lower priority ISR. This gets into a really complex realm and sometimes requires providing the code protection for certain variables by disabling the interrupts in the specific peripherals instead.

Comment: @MichaelKaras No, i mean the flags that invoke individual interrupts. I indeed had one of those lines, it just were carefully hiding from me in the middle of lookalike lines where you set a bit to a bitfield. But I'm now well into coding a new branch without that code in there so yeah. Also, I'm not new to programming voodoo and just generally don't shy away from it in favor of easily comprehensible solutions. I'm only new to microcontrollers, but honestly, they don't feel alien even a notch.

Answer (score 4):

Why do you say it is random or impossible to debug?  I don't even see it as a compiler issue.  It's more poor realtime software design.

You have main code which writes to a variable.  You have ISR which writes to the same variable.  This sounds problematic to me.  You disable interrupts and code crashes.  You have a shared resource, even if it is just a memory location.  You have to implement some form of resource sharing or change code to eliminate problem.

You isolated problem to main code, which was interrupted while writing to variable.  ISR writes to variable, but main code writes over variable when ISR returns.  Voila, your ISR data is lost.  Sequential code with an ISR which can occur at any time.

Lots of solutions.  Easiest is a software interrupt.  Have main program call ISR to write it's data.  Assuming you disable ISRs in ISR.

Personally, I'd rethink how to do what you want by separating main program from ISR.

Comment: It didn't crossed my mind that a single 8-bit write operation wouldn't be atomic, and you don't need any concurrency measures for atomic operations, which is why there wasn't any.

Comment: But you're not doing a single 8-bit write. Your BITSET and BITCLR macros use |= and &=, both of which require read-modify-write as Michael wrote in his answer.